# jQuery one page nav: highlight bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with the jQuery one page nav menu:
when i load my page, the menu highlight randomly the first or the second menu item. I need the menu to highlight everytime only the "home" item.
I'm using "jquery.nav.js" without any modification, so i can't found where is the problem, probably in the page code.
You can check the page here: http://folsom.it/ferrari/it/
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen because you have runtime errors:

```
2016-10-17 11:29:47.225 (index):25 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)
2016-10-17 11:29:47.225 (index):33 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)
2016-10-17 11:29:47.296 (index):977 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)
2016-10-17 11:29:47.322 (index):1042 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)
2016-10-17 11:29:47.399 (index):1242 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Fix these errors and you'll see your code will work a bit more as expected.

You can fix the `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` errors by loading jQuery before these lines are executed.

Comment: Thanks, i've fixed the runtime errors. Despite this, the menu behavior is not changed. The issue is still the same.

Comment: OK. Now add the class `current` to the first list item in your nav element

Comment: Done, but still not working. If i open the inspector, i can see the `current` class was dinamically assigned to the second item

Comment: OK. I can see it going wrong because the .getSection (jquery.nav.js:128) retrieves two zero values for the home-slider and the our-story section. This happens because `$target.offset().top;` (jquery.nav.js:122) returns zero on the our-story element. I'd suggest adding a height to your home-slider up front.

Comment: Ok Egidius, i'm not a developer but i understand the problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "adding a height to your home-slider up front", exactly? Add a height to the home-slider section css? or to the menu element css?

Comment: To the slider section. This happens somewhere else in your code (I see it's being set programmatically, but my educated guess is that this happens after the jquery.nav code is initiated.

Comment: I did some tests, but the behavior does not change. I'll wait for your further help, when you can. Thanks, i appreciate!

Comment: OK well, let's try this: you have a duplicate ID for two of your sections. They are both called `our-story`. Change either one of those

Comment: Done, but nothing changed. :(

Comment: OK Well, I'm running out of options as I'm not able to properly debug your page. This is not something to be proud of but it might solve your problem at least. Add this to the very bottom of your page: `$(document).ready(function() { $('.current').removeClass('current'); $("ul#nav a[href='#home-slider']").parent().addClass('current');
[li.page-scroll.menu-item.current] });`

Comment: Ok i see what you're trying to do, unfortunately the script doesn't work.
From the inspector i get this runtime error:
`(index):1307 Uncaught ReferenceError: li is not defined`

Comment: Ah darn. Something went wrong in my copy pasting from my console :-). This is what I ment: `$(document).ready(function() { $('.current').removeClass('current'); $("ul#nav a[href='#home-slider']").parent().addClass('current'); });` Let's pray for this to work

Comment: Ok now i have no more runtime errors, but the behavior does not change.

Comment: OK well, I'd suggest replacing jquery.nav.js by scrollSpy: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy which is a proven solution for the same problem.

Comment: Ok, if there arent' more options i'll try scrollSpy. Thank you for your help, i hope to not bothering you anymore